# AngularJs focus on particular Field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here i created simple program  using angularJs , here how to focus on particular field  when error occurred
Thanks in advance

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  
  $scope.save=function(){
    
      if($scope.firstName != undefined){
          if($scope.firstName.length < 3)   {
              alert("Please Enter More that 3 char");
            
            }
        
        
        }
    
    }
 
 
     
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  <form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/>
      <input type="submit"  ng-click="save()"/>
  </form>
  
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it will focus the element that contain the error when you try to submit the form.
your html :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <form name="formname" id="form1" novalidate ng-submit="form(formname)">
      <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
  </form>


</body>
```

and in your controller write this code

```
$scope.form =  function (form) {
                var firstError = null;
                if (form.$invalid) {

                    var field = null, firstError = null;
                    for (field in form) {
                        if (field[0] != '$') {
                            if (firstError === null && !form[field].$valid) {
                                firstError = form[field].$name;
                            }

                            if (form[field].$pristine) {
                                form[field].$dirty = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    angular.element('.ng-invalid[name=' + firstError + ']').focus();
                   return;
                } else {

                    $scope.save()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is simple and easiest way to focus on element. you will be able to focus on element using javascript.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" id="firstName" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="save()" />
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.save = function () {
        if ($scope.firstName != undefined) {
            if ($scope.firstName.length < 3) {
                alert("Please Enter More that 3 char");
                var element = $window.document.getElementById("firstName");
                if (element)
                    element.focus();
            }
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```